# How to create dynamic if-conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to make a dynamic filter method, but don't know how to include conditions dynamically.

**Example**

```
var do_test_1 = true,
    do_test_2 = false,
    do_test_3 = true;
```

Now there are three tests:

```
if (foo == bar)  // test 1
if (john == doe) // test 2
if (jane == doe) // test 3
```

Now I want to build a dynamic if clause, based on the `do_test` vars.

**Real use case**

I have a list of tasks and want to filter them:

- If the "assigned to me" filter is active, it should return only the the tasks that are assigned to me.
- If the "high priority" filter and the "assigned to me" filter is active, it should return only the tasks that are assigned to me and have a high priority.
- ... and so on ...

I played around with the `filter` method, but I only get it working with an OR logic (show tasks that are assigned to me or have a high priority):

```
var $show = $tasks.filter(function(index, task) {
  var $task = $(task);
  return ((task.data('assigned') && filters['mytasks']) || (task.data('priority') == 3 && filters['priority']))
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `eval()` function

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var f=i+1;
    eval("if(f==i+1){alert(i);}");   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ke42b/2/

This is just a tip on how to create dynamic if conditions. Now you know how to create dynamic if conditions.

Code accordingly to your needs !